# AVR GCC - typecasting trouble

Tags: c, casting, bit-manipulation, avr

I'm using an AVR microcontroller to write to a programmable frequency divider chip via the I2C bus.  At certain intervals I'm trying to have the following function is called to update the frequency output of the chip:

```
void 1077WriteDiv(int16_t data)
{
    uint8_t upperByte = (uint8_t)((uint16_t)data>>2);

    i2c_start(DS1077_BASE_ADDRESS);
    i2c_write(DIVIDE_REGISTER);
    i2c_write(upperByte);
    i2c_write(0x0);
    i2c_stop();
}
```

I'm trying to get the top 8 bits of a ten bit value in the "data" variable and write it out.  The second "write" command writes the lower 8 bits of the "divide" register on the chip, 0 in this case.

As a test case I'm incrementing the "data" variable (which has to be signed for certain reasons) from zero, shifting it left 2 bits and calling this function each time.  I get garbage out.  However, when I do this:

```
 void 1077WriteDiv(int16_t data)
    {
        //uint8_t upperByte = (uint8_t)((uint16_t)data>>2);
            static uint8_t thing = 0;     

        i2c_start(DS1077_BASE_ADDRESS);
        i2c_write(DIVIDE_REGISTER);
        i2c_write(thing++);
        i2c_write(0x0);
        i2c_stop();
    }
```

Everything works as expected.  There's obviously some kind of problem in how I'm shifting and typecasting the original "data" variable, but I've tried all kinds of permutations with the same results.  It would be much appreciated if anyone could point out where I might be going wrong.

Comment: Could you show us the code that is doing the incrementing and left shifting?  Maybe that code is bad.

Comment: Please show us the calling code...

Comment: gcc isn't *really* letting you use `1077WriteDiv` as an identifier, is it?  Can you show us your real code?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `>>2` and not `CHAR_BIT` or `8`?

Comment: @ephemient he says top 8 bits of a 10 bit value...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
uint8_t upperByte = (uint8_t) ((data & 0x3FC) >> 2);
```

You cannot rely on the cast to a smaller int to delete the high-order bits that you are trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

```
i2c_write(thing++);
```

Would mean your divider increments every call.  If you increment "data" and shift it right by two then your divider increments every **four** calls.  Your two code sections are not equivalent.

What interval are you calling this function at?  What is "garbage out"?  How do you know the value passed into the function is correct?  How do you know the value sent out to the DS1077 is wrong?

**Check all your assumptions.**

The cast and shift look fine to me.  At least I think they'd work in any C compiler I've ever used.  From a C standard perspective you can refer to this draft ([ISO/IEC 9899:TC2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) 6.3 Conversions):

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type

Which is the only one I have access to right now.  Perhaps someone else can chime in on the standard question.  The compiler may not be standard compliant...

Comment: Unfortunately it's seeming more likely that this is some obscure hardware problem.  I've spent several hours looking carefully at the disassembler and stepping through the code on a simulator, and in simulation everything works perfectly.  I'm really having trouble finding a reason why the _software_ wouldn't work properly.

Comment: @Bitrex revise the question with your detailed findings and maybe someone can help you...  Unfortunately most problems are obscure until the "duh" momemnt :-)